# Shoud I load Vue JS manually in laravel?

Tags: laravel-vue

I have added some Vue Code in a view in a Laravel project. Do I need to include the vuejs in the layout like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.12/vue.js"></script>
```

Or laravel takes care of it in someway.

What I have tried:

I ran `npm install` and `npm run dev` and I have now `app.js` and `app.css` in the public directory.

and I have the following in the view:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
  comments: {},
  post: {!! $post->toJson() !!},
  user: {!! Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->toJson() : 'null' !!},
  comment: 'Your Comment'
},
mounted(){
  this.getComments();
},
methods:{
  getComments(){
    //Some code here
  }
}
});
```

But when I access this view I get:

```
ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You should add your script in your index file

2- then add that vue codes in the app.js file in the resources\js\app.js

Answer (score 0):

Run npm prod to compile the vue file and add it at the end of the body tag where you want it to use.

**How Vue.js is used in laravel**

when we run npm install it will download all packages to `node_modules` directory that are mentioned in the `webpack.mix.js.` 
Then we add required plugins in `resources/js/app.js`.

In `resources/js/app.js`  we initialize vue.js using

```
new Vue(
     el:'#id_of_the_element'
})
```

Then we run `npm run prod` to compile the minified version of vue.js and place it `public/js/app.js` now it can be added where required

```
<html>
  <body>
      <div id="id_of_the_element">
         //....
      </div>
      //import your app.js here
      <script src="/js/app.js">
   </body>
</html>
```